# Windows 7 autorun enabled... yet disabled?

Tags: windows-7, windows, autorun

The checkbox "Use AutoPlay for all media and devices" is checked.

Yet, at some point in time, my computer has stopped giving me AutoPlay prompts.

I can't really elaborate beyond this because that's basically all there is to observe.

Does anyone know of a solution?

**EDIT 19/03/2010:** I have attempted to disable and renable AutoPlay a few times to no avail, in case you're going to suggest it. All options are on "Ask me every time".

**EDIT 21/03/2010:** HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\cdrom\AutoRun is and was set to 1

Comment: I have noticed the exact same problem, with 2 different installs of Win7. It works fine for a period of time after initial installation of Windows then at some point it just stops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Windows AutoPlay system is quite complex and its behavior depends on a lot of registry settings.

[image]

Unfortunately, the AutoPlay Control Panel applet in Windows 7 doesn’t allow you to change system-wide settings. So it’s possible that ”Use AutoPlay for all media and devices” is checked, but AutoPlay is still disabled.

To enable AutoPlay use either of the following methods:

**Using Group Policy Editor**

Open **Local Group Policy Editor** (gpedit.msc), navigate to **Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / AutoPlay Policies** and change the **Turn off AutoPlay** policy to **Disabled**.

After that you can reset it to Not Configured, which is the default state.

**Using Regedit**
Unfortunately Group Policy Editor isn’t available on Windows Home editions, as an alternative you can use regedit.

Open **regedit** and locate the following key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

change (or if it doesn't exist create a new DWORD) `NoDriveTypeAutorun`  to `0x91`

For more information please read the following KB article:
[How to disable the Autorun functionality in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967715/en-us)

Comment: I'll give this a go tonight when I get home...

Comment: This worked for me, although it was already set to Not Configured - I set it to Enabled, then Disabled, then back to Not Configured (clicking apply after each one) and I now have my AutoPlay working again! Many thanks...

Comment: I unfortunately can't access `gpedit.msc`; I'm on Windows 7 Home Premium.

Comment: I tried following the link mentioning `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\ CurrentVersion\policies\Explorer\NoDriveTypeAutorun`, but my regedit shows that policies doesn't contain anything beyond (Default). Perhaps I could create a sub-key, but the link only shows the value for disabling, not enabling.

Comment: Check the key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, not HKEY_CURRENT_USER. Machine settings override per-user settings.
The deafult value for NoDriveTypeAutorun is 0x91 for Vista & Windows 7.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret the value for the HKLM key, it currently says `ff` in the edit dialog - do I change it to 91?

Comment: Yes, change it to 0x91.
According to the above mentioned KB article 0xff disables AutoRun on all kinds of drives.

Comment: It worked! Thank you, enjoy your +100 rep :)

Answer (score 1):

Besides **Use AutoPlay for all media and devices** make sure you have the **Ask me every time** option set for all items under **Media** and **Devices**

[image]

Comment: Everything is on "Ask me every time" already.