# AutoPlay settings shows enabled even when I disable it through group policy

Tags: windows, windows-10, group-policy, autoplay

I have *disabled* AutoPlay through group policy by *enabling* **Turn off Autoplay** at

Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates ? Windows Components > AutoPlay Policies

and have rebooted system for policy to take effect but control panel/windows settings still shows it is enabled.

Why don't they not sync?

What is the best and reliable way to disable it for all users?

This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/124393/475817) is related but doesn't quite answer my question.

Comment: What about the other question does not answer yours? Have you gone through all of the settings listed in that answer?

Comment: @music2myear It talks of group policy and registry method is if you don't have group policy. The same is stated in official microsoft doc linked [there](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/967715/how-to-disable-the-autorun-functionality-in-windows) but its not for Windows 10. The question is why control panel does't respond to it?